# Does writeToFile:atomically:YES have a limit for file size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to write a file using

`writeToFile:atomically:YES`

However, I`m not succesful with every file. When I'm trying to write a large array (created from four parsed XML documents), the file isn't written (it does succeed when I'm trying to write an array containing only one parsed XML). And it also work, when I'm using

```
writeToFile:atomically:NO
```

What could be the reason of this kind of a behaviour? Is there a limit for file size when using
 `writeToFile:atomically:YES`?

Comment: How large is your array?  1000 elements? 1,000,000?

Comment: Can you use `writeToFile: options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:` and look at the error?

Comment: @ Black Frog It's a complex structure (as it's based on the XML file), but I'd say it has approximately 1000 elements (most of them being property values (or property values of the subarrays - for example name, title, minValue, maxValue etc))

Comment: @vaderkvarn Hmm, seems to be working using this one. I'd prefer to do it without NSMutableArray->NSData->NSMutableArray conversion though (by doing `[myArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];`)

Comment: @vaderkvarn Sorry, I was using the wrong array. As my array elements are custom class objects, converting to NSData seems to be needing some additional encoding as it gives me a crash right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only size limit is the amount of available space on the device. However, `writeToFile:atomically:` only works on an NSArray if every object, all the way down however many levels it goes, is a property list object. Property list objects are `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, and `NSData`. Also, `NSDictionary` is only a property list object if the keys are all `NSString`.

`NSArray` **does** conform to `NSCoding` though, so if your custom class objects also conform to `NSCoding` then you could encode the array into an `NSData` and write that to a file-- via `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Alternately, clean up your data structure so you're only using property list objects.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the answer. However, it's weird that I succeeded with `writeToFile:atomically:NO` and also with one-member array. I made my custom class conform to NSCoding now and the file was written successfully.